# Hashing passwords with exact same inputs doesn't output the same value

Tags: php, encryption, sha256

I'm trying to hash the password if you sign up on my website, but it doesn't work.
This is my code to hash the password upon signing up:

```
$escapedName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']); 
$escapedPW = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));

$hashedPW = hash('sha256', $escapedPW . $salt);
```

Then I just insert it in a database (the hashed password and the salt).
For example, when I hash `Sas`, with the following salt:
`abac7ad23185ad19967f0d13e962197962782f0b7ec32d9889c27a93a9e800fa`
This is the hashed password:
`8ca5c5f31fafbf382533dbcbfc22b3635d776ec7770c7eac58d8ef9f1fa3613c`

But when I try to hash the password on log in, with the exact same password and salt, this becomes the hashed pass:
`6eb4b16444f18cee19db32bd29a39970e3019c5b1972a982ae4cb9a59642dffc`

This is the code I use to login:

```
$escapedName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$escapedPW = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$saltQuery = mysql_query("SELECT salt FROM members WHERE user='{$escapedName}'");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($saltQuery)) {
    $salt = $result['salt'];
}

$hashedPW = hash('sha256', $escapedPW . $salt);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE user='$escapedName' AND pass='$hashedPW'; ");
while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    $username = $res['user'];
    $PW = $res['pass'];
}
```

I hope it's not too much code and I also hope you will understand my question.

Comment: Do you retrieve the salt correctly?

Comment: @MathieuImbert I suppose so, I've posted my code where I retrieve it, so what do you think?

Comment: Make sure the length of the stored salt is the same as what you get back. Same for the two passwords. Any extra CR/LN will throw the hash off.

Comment: Did you compare the salt you send to the DB and the one you retrieve from the DB? Manually? Clearly if you don't get the same output with the same function callm it's because your input is broken. Use `var_dump()` and compare the strings.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't comment but something tells me that there is a length restriction on the `salt` column in your database.

Example: The salt field might only allow a 64 characters while the generated salt might be longer therefore when you save the salt it gets trimmed which ultimately changes the hashed password.

If that's the case, you might want to trim the salt before saving it.

I'd advise using [PDO](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to make queries against your database.

Comment: I have a varchar(255) for storing the salt.

Comment: can you make sure that there isn't multiple salt for one user? Can you update your question the DB structure?

Comment: And you are 100% sure that the hash before and after you save it is exactly the same? I don't see anything that would cause an issue in your code. Also in the first query you are using brackets around the username however you are not using brackets in the second one. Also I've had issue with word `user` in the past try to escape it with tildas.

Comment: It's not working and I'm too lazy to do something about it. Instead of actually solving the problem, I made a script that uses sha512 with no salt. Is that convenient, or should you really use salt?

Comment: You should use a salt; it doesn't have to be a salt of 64 characters, 10 characters is enough. If you plan on making your solution open source I'd advise using an extra salt called "secret" which is set as a config parameter for the application and also a parameter that specifies how many times the password should be re-hashed.

Comment: There, it still worked when I added a salt. And no, I wasn't planning to make it open source.

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs to the hash function must be different for some reason or other.

Add log output messages that print your inputs before you hash for both use cases (create user and login).  Also be sure to put quotes around the inputs in your logging to show whitespace issues.

Compare the raw inputs as well as the output of the hash function in both cases, and there will be a difference somewhere.  If there is no difference, and the output of the hash is the same, then there is a problem in your query that is looking up the user in the login case.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're doing, it's insecure if you WANT the hashes to be the same! See http://php.net/crypt for proper password hashing.

All you need:

```
function check_password($password) {  
    ...//get db password to compare
    if (crypt($post_password, $db_results[0]['password']) == $db_results[0]['password']) {  
        return true;  
    } else { return false; }
}
```